# react-devtools: By default DevTools listen to port 8097 on localhost. How to customise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

I'm trying to install the standalone react-devtools, which by default listens to port 8097. My app uses port 3001. The documentation says the following:

"By default DevTools listen to port 8097 on localhost.
If you need to customize host, port, or other settings, see the react-devtools-core package instead."

How do I go about changing the port to listen to 3001 instead?

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs advise to have a look at [`react-devtools-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools-core):

> ```
> require('react-devtools-core').connectToDevTools(options)
> ```
>
> This is similar to `require('react-devtools')` in another package but
>   providing more control. Unlike `require('react-devtools')`, it doesn't
>   connect immediately, but exports a function.
>
> Run `connectToDevTools()` in the same context as React to set up a
>   connection to DevTools. Make sure this runs before any `react`,
>   `react-dom`, or `react-native` imports.
>
> The options object may contain:
>
> - host (string), defaults to `'localhost'`.
> - port (number), defaults to `8097`.
> - resolveRNStyle (function), used by RN and `null` by default.

Comment: humble, literally.

Comment: Where should I put this for **React Native**? I have tried put at root `index.js` and `App.js`, then run `npx react-devtools` and it doesn't change at all. The docs isn't helpful much, there's no issue on GitHub about it and it stress me out that there's no example for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also change your emulator or device port to 8097. Worked for me.

Eg: `adb -s <device-name> reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097`

How to find device name: run `adb devices`

Comment: How do you change the device port? The command you showed is just for port forwarding.