# Change port of react devtools

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

I'm trying to setup my environment to develop with react-native and react-devtools.
Per default the react-devtool uses port 8097 to connect with the app on the emulator.
Unfortunatley, this port is blocked at my workplace. Where/How can i change this port?

I found out that there's an option to configure the devtools with:

```
const { connectToDevTools } = require("react-devtools-core");
connectToDevTools( { port: "customport" } );
```

I just don't know where to place this config.

I managed to change the app so that it tries to connect to a different port, but i can't seem to change wart port the devtool client (?) uses  [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9JY.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-devtools: By default DevTools listen to port 8097 on localhost. How to customise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074677/react-devtools-by-default-devtools-listen-to-port-8097-on-localhost-how-to-cus)

Comment: This question seems answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074677/react-devtools-by-default-devtools-listen-to-port-8097-on-localhost-how-to-cus

Comment: As i wrote above: i found that thread, but i don't know where exactly i should add that, ie.e which file. I added it my my App.tsx, but the client in the screenshot linked above still shows that port 8097 is uesd

Comment: Anyone here able to share their example? I'm running out of ideas on how to put the instance.